# Unable to track eyes using camshift in Python opencv ; The bounding Box comes at the wrong position

Tags: opencv

the code shows no error, but the tracker box is not at the correct place. Instead of the eye it tracks the face . I think there is some logical error which i am not getting. instead of tracking the eye it tracks the face. maybe there is some error in getting the tracking window or in the usgae of the camshift function

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,frame = cap.read()
face_detect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\opencv2410\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
faces = face_detect.detectMultiScale(frame,1.3,5)
[x,y,w,h] = faces[0,:]
roi_face = frame[y:y+h,x:x+h]
eye_detect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\opencv2410\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_mcs_eyepair_big.xml')
eyes = eye_detect.detectMultiScale(roi_face,1.3,5)
[ex,ey,ew,eh] = eyes[0,:]
track_window = (x+ex,y+ey,ew,eh)

roi_eye = frame[y+ey:y+ey+eh,x+ex:x+ex+ew]


hsv_roi_eye = cv2.cvtColor(roi_eye,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_roi_eye,np.array((0.,60.,32.)), np.array((180.,255.,255.)))
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi_eye],[0],mask,[180],[0,180])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist,roi_hist,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

term_crit = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT,10,1)

while(1) :
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    if ret ==True :
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv],[0],roi_hist,[0,180],1)

        ret, track_window = cv2.CamShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

        pts = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(ret)
        pts = np.int0(pts)

        cv2.polylines(frame,[pts],True,255,2)
        cv2.imshow('output',frame)

        k= cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k== 27 :
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```